# Spring integration Kinesis - no proper implementation found

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-stream

I'm running this sample - [Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Sample By Spring cloud](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kinesis-produce-consume).

My credentials inside `.aws` folder under my user-folder in `Windows 7`.

When starting the application, I get the following exceptions:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-06 15:31:47.739 ERROR 14140 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kinesisMessageChannelBinder' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.KinesisMessageChannelBinder]: Factory method 'kinesisMessageChannelBinder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/provisioning/ProvisioningProvider;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) [spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:214) [spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.BUILD-20170928.175652-73.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:155) [spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.BUILD-20170928.175652-73.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:155) [spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.BUILD-20170928.175652-73.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:111) [spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.BUILD-20170928.175652-73.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:238) [spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.BUILD-20170928.175652-73.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:57) [spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.BUILD-20170928.175652-73.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175) [spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50) [spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348) [spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151) [spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114) [spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880) [spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) [spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at demo.KinesisApplication.main(KinesisApplication.java:38) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.KinesisMessageChannelBinder]: Factory method 'kinesisMessageChannelBinder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/provisioning/ProvisioningProvider;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/provisioning/ProvisioningProvider;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.KinesisMessageChannelBinder.<init>(KinesisMessageChannelBinder.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-1.0.0.BUILD-20180306.025109-72.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration.kinesisMessageChannelBinder(KinesisBinderConfiguration.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-1.0.0.BUILD-20180306.025109-72.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c56040f.CGLIB$kinesisMessageChannelBinder$1(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-1.0.0.BUILD-20180306.025109-72.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c56040f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2200056c.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-1.0.0.BUILD-20180306.025109-72.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c56040f.kinesisMessageChannelBinder(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-1.0.0.BUILD-20180306.025109-72.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted

2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  WARN 14140 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform binding, no proper implementation found
2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  INFO 14140 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  INFO 14140 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  INFO 14140 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: ordersIn
2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  INFO 14140 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: ordersOut
2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  INFO 14140 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: nullChannel
2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  INFO 14140 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: errorChannel
2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  INFO 14140 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Summary on shutdown: _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler
2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  INFO 14140 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  INFO 14140 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  INFO 14140 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  INFO 14140 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  INFO 14140 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2018-03-06 15:31:47.755  INFO 14140 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2018-03-06 15:31:47.771  INFO 14140 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-06 15:31:47.771 ERROR 14140 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform binding, no proper implementation found
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at demo.KinesisApplication.main(KinesisApplication.java:38) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform binding, no proper implementation found
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:61) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.BUILD-20170928.175652-73.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kinesisMessageChannelBinder' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.KinesisMessageChannelBinder]: Factory method 'kinesisMessageChannelBinder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/provisioning/ProvisioningProvider;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:214) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.BUILD-20170928.175652-73.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:155) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.BUILD-20170928.175652-73.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:155) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.BUILD-20170928.175652-73.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:111) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.BUILD-20170928.175652-73.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:238) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.BUILD-20170928.175652-73.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.BUILD-20170928.175652-73.jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.KinesisMessageChannelBinder]: Factory method 'kinesisMessageChannelBinder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/provisioning/ProvisioningProvider;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/provisioning/ProvisioningProvider;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.KinesisMessageChannelBinder.<init>(KinesisMessageChannelBinder.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-1.0.0.BUILD-20180306.025109-72.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration.kinesisMessageChannelBinder(KinesisBinderConfiguration.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-1.0.0.BUILD-20180306.025109-72.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c56040f.CGLIB$kinesisMessageChannelBinder$1(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-1.0.0.BUILD-20180306.025109-72.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c56040f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2200056c.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-1.0.0.BUILD-20180306.025109-72.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c56040f.kinesisMessageChannelBinder(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-1.0.0.BUILD-20180306.025109-72.jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fully related to what we have with the open Pull Request: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/pull/60

The problem that Spring Cloud Stream AWS Kinesis Binder isn't compatible with the current Spring Cloud Stream version - the Spring Boot/Spring Cloud `2.0` are requirements.

What you need to do is like perform similar changes I did in the Pull Request. Essentially change this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

to the `2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` version.